# How to copy all .conf files and enable each of them in ubuntu-apache environment

Tags: linux, bash, apache

I need a short version of this script

```
cp apache-conf/site1.conf /etc/apache2/sites-available
cp apache-conf/site2.conf /etc/apache2/sites-available
cp apache-conf/site..N.conf /etc/apache2/sites-available
a2ensite site1
a2ensite site2
a2ensite site..N
```

I can `cp apache-conf/*.conf /etc/apache2/sites-available` but how about enabling each of them?

Comment: You should _accept_ one of them as the working answer. Click on the tick-mark next to the answer of your choice

Answer (score 1):

Please Use the following command

```
find /etc/apache2/sites-available/ -type f -and -not -name "*default*" -exec a2ensite {} \;
```

This finds all your configuration files that are not having "default" in their name and activates them.

If you face any errors, please have a look at this thread
Credits: https://askubuntu.com/questions/916377/how-to-enable-all-site-confs-with-a2ensite-while-passing-over-000-default-conf/917701

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of the powerhouse built-in utils in `bash` that allows globbing with the number on the part of the filename

```
# To avoid un-expanded globs being treated as valid entries
shopt -s nullglob

for file in apache-conf/site[0-9]*.conf; do
    cp -- "$file" /etc/apache2/sites-available
done
```

Assuming `N` is static and *not* known at run-time, you can do something as below. Consider a case of being it `10`

```
for file in apache-conf/site{0..10}.conf; do
    cp -- "$file" /etc/apache2/sites-available
done
```

and for running the command `a2ensite` on the destination path

```
for file in /etc/apache2/sites-available/*.conf; do
    a2ensite "$(basename -- "$file")"
done
```